# cannot see monitor metrics

Tags: apache-flink, metrics

My ENV: flink-1.4,kafka-0.10,cdh-5.11.1

I'm running flink on yarn, Im sure my program is OK, but I just cannot see the monitor metrics, As shown in the picture below :

[image]

AND here is the Job DAG:

[image]

Comment: Please post an image of Job DAG, it might give some more idea.

Answer (score 1):

Those statistics might be a bit misleading at first. They correspond to a single operator chain. They say how many bytes/records were sent/received by this chain. Because your whole DAG consists of only a single chain you see zeros in there.

If you want to see metrics for underlying operators go to Task Metrics -> from the drop down list choose a metric you want to see.